# How can I use a TypeError to catch an error (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I created a Palindrome Game where a user is asked for a word and will get a response saying if it is a palindrome or if it isn't. I wanna check to make sure that the user has input a string and not a number and to try to catch it.

**My goal is to catch the error when the user inputs a number and not a string**

```
while True:
    try:
        ask = list(input("Enter a word: "))
        #print(ask[::-1])

        if ask == ask[::-1]:
            print('Great! Your word was a Palindrome')

        else:
            print('''Sorry! Next time FOH SHO!''')

    except TypeError:
        print('Must be letters!')
```

Comment: `input()` will return a string (in python3), so maybe you need to check if this string contains only letters ?

Comment: Just use the built-in string function [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha).

Comment: `input` *always* returns a string. You want to check if that string contains only letters. A `ValueError` is the appropriate exception to raise in that case.

Comment: @chepner I tried ValueError except it didn't work :/

Comment: No, you are trying to *catch* a `ValueError`. `input` isn't going to raise any exception; you have to check the return value of `input` yourself, then you can *raise* a `ValueError` if it contains any non-letters.

Comment: `list(input(...))` will always succeed as well, since it will just a return a list of single-character strings corresponding to the single string returned by `input`.

Comment: @chepner Ohh okay I see what you're trying to say now and how that would work as well. Thanks for helping out as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the condition [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) for string input

```
while True:
  ask = input("Enter a word: ")

  if not ask.isalpha():
    print("Must be letters")
    continue

  if ask == ask[::-1]:
    print('Great! Your word was a Palindrome')

  else:
    print('''Sorry! Next time FOH SHO!''')
```

Comment: Hey that works! Thank you so much!! What does isalpha() do in this case?

Comment: Check out the link to see all methods for string shared in comments, it will check for only alphabets. Other methods like `isalnum()` etc. does other operations.